# ExpressJS / NodeJS routing traffic to the base URL instead of root?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route defined as:

```
router.get('/console/:labID?', (req, res, next) => {
```

When this route gets called, all additional requests are appended to /console to give you a request similar to :

```
/console/<new request>
```

I'm assuming this is intended functionality and I need to reset the route somewhere based on the request?  Occasionally I will want to append it but where do I control this behavior?

Comment: Are you looking for `res.redirect()` http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect?

Comment: @jsalonen - I just realized why I this wasn't working as I don't have a leading slash on my requests...  Reading through that pointed that out to me...  Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me that you might be looking for "relative URLs" and "root-relative URLs": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls#answer-39545949